# SQL Server transactional replication, and adding new tables

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have a very large existing set of tables being replicated (transactional) between two servers over a dedicated VPN connection.  I need to add a new table.  Reloading all the tables is not an option.

I thought that by simply adding the new articles to the publication it would replicate them across, but that didn't work.  Of course, something needs to tell the subscriber about the new articles.  I then chose Generate Snapshot on the publisher, but I couldn't tell what it was doing (maybe scripting out *all* the data?) so I shut it down.  Maybe I should have let it run? I'm not sure.

So how do I safely add the new articles to the existing subscription?

Comment: Did you create the table definition on the subscriber end before turning on the new publication article?

Comment: No, usually it does that automatically. Should I be doing it manually? If so, how? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer. The problem is that I did not use the initial snapshot to initialize the subscriber in the first place. I used a different method (the backup and restore method), which means I have to manually transfer the schema and data before starting up the transactional replication process.

Comment: I initialized our subscriber in the same way and had come to the same conclusion as you but it's nice to see it confirmed bny someone else!